# How to get rid of black bar below FinishedSelectedImage of TabBarItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Problem with FinishedSelectedImages.
I got this code:

`[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"measure_tabBar_m.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"measure_tabBar.png"]];`

And now I have a some space below my Images and behind that space there is the TabBar. I already tried to just make the height of the .png Files bigger but it didn't help. Does anyone know how to get rid of this space between bottom of the screen an my Tab Images ?

Answer (score 1):

This API is really poorly documented.

Your `finishedSelectedImage` should be an icon ~30x30px. No doubt you have (as I did) created a `finishedSelectedImage`, complete with a background, that's 49px high (the full height of the tabBar). Then system places the bottom of this image above the space where the `tabBarItem.title` resides.

If you want a fully customised tabBar style, you also need to specify a `tabBar.backgroundImage` (49px high, full-screen width) and a `tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage` (49px high, single-tab-width).

Conceptually, you start with a full-width `backgroundImage` for the tabBar, add a `selectionIndicatorImage` which functions as the background image for the selected tab, then add a two versions of each tab's icon, `finishedUnselectedImage` and `finishedSelectedImage`.